# How to run MovieClip ( who is an external swf ) function from flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash, movieclip

I try to call swf function ( setPoints(nr:int):void; ) from flex.

```
[Embed(source="img/anim/x2.swf")]
[Bindable]
public static var points:Class;

public function strikeAnimation(area:SpriteVisualElement, strike:int):void{
  var mc:MovieClip  =  new points() as MovieClip;
  area.addChild(mc);
  //how to run?
  area.mc.setpoints(strike);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you having a problem?  And if so; what is the problem?  Why doesn't this work for you?

Comment: I tried call function like this  -   
area.getChildIndex(area.getChildIndex(mc)).setpoints(strike);
But flex showed me an error --
Multiple markers at this line:
-area
-area
-1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type int to an unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.
-1061: Call to a possibly undefined method fire through a reference with static type int.
-Access of undefined property setpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried call function like this -
>   area.getChildIndex(area.getChildIndex(mc)).setpoints(strike);

The reason you received an error with the line of code above is that [getChildIndex](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildIndex%28%29) expects a DisplayObject and returns an Integer.

So, this probably worked:

```
area.getChildIndex(mc)
```

But, it returned an integer which you can't use as the input to another getChildIndex call because an integer is not the same as a child.

Something like this should get you an instance of your child:

```
var myChild :MovieClip = area.getChildAt(area.getChildIndex(mc))
```

However, the setpoints method is not a documented method of a [movieclip](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html); so to execute the setpoints method on your custom movie clip you're going to have to convert it to your custom type.  Conceptually something like this:

```
(myChild as myCustomType).setpoints(strike);
```